# print using Epson TM-T20ii network printer on andorid

Tags: chrome-for-android, thermal-printer

Im trying to print from browser to network thermal printer, the problem is when trying to print invoices its doesn't do anything, the printer is Epson  TM-T20ii thermal printer, connected by network, what is the best solution for this.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It would help if you could describe your setup a bit closer. E.g.: What are you using to print – a specific app? Have you tried an [alternative printer app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_print) already?